# Schrödinger Equation in Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Hi can anyone help me with this question?

Let $u\in C^2(B(0,1))$, where $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball, such that $u$ vanishes at the boundary and let $u$ solve the Schrödinger equation
$\Delta u-V(x)u=f(x)$ with $f\in L^\infty$ and $V(x)\ge 1$ such that $V(x)\in L^\infty$.

I now have to find a bound for $||u||_{H^1}$ in terms of $||f||_{L^2}$

Answer (score 1):

We have, with $B=B(0,1)$, multiplying by $u$ both sides of the equation and integrating by parts (recall $u$ vanishes at the boundary)
$$
\int_B |\nabla u|^2 +u^2 dx \leq \int_B |\nabla u |^2 dx + V(x)u^2 dx = -\int_B fudx \leq \| u\|_{L^2}\| f\|_{L^2},
$$
where the first inequality is because $V\geq1$ and the last one is Cauchy-Schwarz. Therefore we get
$$
\| u\|_{H^1}^2 \leq \| f\|_{L^2}\| u\|_{L^2}\leq  \| f\|_{L^2}\| u\|_{H^1}.
$$
This is what you want.